# Image wrapping without repetition in JavaFX 3D

Tags: javafx-8

Is there a way to wrap an image around a Box or Cylinder in JavaFX without causing it to repeat on the each side?? I do not want to create a custom cube unless there is no other way to do that, using existing JavaFX functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a TriangleMesh and map the UV points for the texture to the Mesh.

James Weaver explains how to do this for a cube in his [powerpoint presentation on JavaFX 3D (pages 24-30)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://oraclecn.activeevents.com/connect/fileDownload/session/74C81CEA20E5DA847E475E91D00A5D65/CON2221_Weaver-exploring-javafx-3d.pptx&ei=MfIEU9anCYXwoATr54DgCw&usg=AFQjCNET-VvL_UQBKBY08FcnhAGR1QCigg&sig2=6xS4TvnsxpIG3wXaxgxVHg&bvm=bv.61535280,d.cGU).  I'd paste the content here, but I'm not sure of copyright and the presentation explains the concepts better than if I tried to describe it here myself.

I know that this isn't exactly the answer you want, but I think this is the only way to do it.